# How long does it take for iPhone end-users to update apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, updates

Assuming that the app doesn't do anything special, like display a push notification telling the user that a new version is available, how long does it take for iPhone users to update an apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that most users seem to update in the first 2 days or so. A lot of users see the badge on the app store and go to their updates whenever they appear.

Comment: I second this - from personal experience and questioning others, it seems that many people see the app store badge and hit update all within a day or two of it appearing.